# How to save user selected slicer selections and the retirve it at later stage in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, power-automate

So I have Multiple slicers containing multiple selections in them and it gets tedious for the user to reselect them every time.

I need assistance with saving the selected slicer option in a Power BI report against some ID.I want to save the selection so that the next time the report is opened and selects the ID, the previously selected slicer combinations will be automatically set.

Eg : User sets [Slicer 1  = A and Slicer 2 = 2 and Slicer 3 = @].This combination is store against an ID [TEST]. SO when user visits the report later he can just select ID as TEST and [Slicer 1  = A and Slicer 2 = 2 and Slicer 3 = @] is automatically set.

Tried using selected values and creating new tables and measures but was not able to get the input and retrieve functionality of the slicer.

Comment: Is this in the service or in desktop? In the Service you can use the 'persistent filters option' https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-persistent-filters-in-the-service/

Comment: Currently in desktop. The above solution does not help me as the user may change the slicer settings to get a different report and need to reselect all the slicer combination to get the first report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One suggestion is to train users to use Personal Bookmarks in Power BI service. See: [Bookmarks in the Power BI service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-bookmarks)
And in Power BI Desktop, bookmarks is also an option.

Comment: Yes seems like this would be easiest and simplest way to achieve what I want.